# loopback 4: Cannot migrate models not attached to this datasource

Tags: node.js, database, migration, loopback

I have created a new loopback project
added datasource to it
added new user model
added this line in migration file
`await app.migrateSchema({existingSchema, models: ['User']});`

then
`npm run migrate`
gives following error
`Cannot migrate models not attached to this datasource: User`

please need help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by creating new loopback4 repository

```
lb4 repository
```